# Create associative array from document.getElementById("ID").value;

Tags: arrays, local-storage

I want to create an associative array from input fields like this:

```
<input id = "city" name = "city" value = "Rochester" />
<input id = "state" name = "state" value = "NY" />
<input id = "zip" name = "zip" value = "14600" />

city = document.getElementById("city").value;
state = document.getElementById("state").value;
zip = document.getElementById("zip").value; 

myArray = [];
```

I want to create this:

```
myArray = [{"city":"Rochester","state":"NY","zip":"14600"}];
```

Is this the correct way and does it require "[]" ?

```
myArray.push({"city" : city, "state" : state, "zip" : zip });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your broader goal? Also, `console.log()` can be used to help see what the results are.

Comment: I have a web app and want to store input values in an array of objects and save those in localStorage.

Comment: Seems like you're doing this part right. Was there any specific issue you are having?

Comment: My problem that I don't know the syntax for referencing items in the array. Both myArray.city and myArray['city'] should work but they don't.

Comment: You're creating an array of objects. So it would be `a[n][k]` as in, for example, `myArray[0]['city']`.

Comment: I figured that out, too! But thank so much for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

I'll abandon storing input values in localStorage in favor of using php and form post to write a few bytes to an external file.txt.